# Touchpad not working but showing up

Tags: dell, touchpad, xinput, peripherals

I know there are multiple questions like this but there was none that helped me till now.
I have a Dell XPS 15 (the 2021 one)

I had the problem on Ubuntu 21.04 then I thought I'd update to 21.10 to fix everything but the problem is still there.

My touchpad isn't recognizing my touches, presses, moves, scrolls, etc. ... But if I input an external mouse, this mouse is working(but the touchpad obviously not).

But it is showing up in /proc/bus/input/devices which you can see [here](https://pastebin.com/8aGvdJpc) Although it does not look similar to all the Debugging tutorials I read. [e.g. this one from ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection) in this one it also writes at point 2. that I shall uninstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics but this isn't even installed, I also am not able to get into the VT (?! never used)  by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F2 but I'm able to get to a terminal without DE by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F7
as well as in xinput --list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Device PID:4055         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K540/K545                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0945:00 04F3:311C Mouse                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0945:00 04F3:311C Touchpad             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Intel HID events                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Logitech K540/K545                        id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

If you want to know more information on my system to help me I'd be happy to share them.

Already thanks for your response

Comment: This problem went away by itself. As the author of this question wrote: *Did nothing and it somehow now works. I didn't restart, I just wrote the question and after I posted it it worked.*

Comment: Having the same issue, DELL098F:00 04F3:311C Touchpad stopped working suddenly out of nowhere. I have Dell XPS 17 2021 with Ubuntu 21.10 on it. Touchpad works in BIOS but not in Ubuntu.

Comment: So, I've finally fixed it by doing the following steps:

1. Turned the touchpad off in the settings.
2. Ran `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` and `sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`.
3. Rebooted the laptop.
4. Turned the touchpad on again, and it's worked.

FWIW I tried all these steps separately before (turn on/off, reboot, bash commands), but it didn't help. Touchpad vendor is Elan.

Answer (score 1):

I have Dell XPS 17 2021 with Ubuntu 21.10 on it. Touchpad vendor is Elan (DELL098F:00 04F3:311C).

I've fixed it by doing the following steps:

1. Turned the touchpad off in the settings.
2. Ran `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` and `sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`.
3. Rebooted the laptop.
4. Turned the touchpad on again, and it's worked.

FWIW I tried all these steps separately before (turn on/off, reboot, bash commands), but it didn't help, and only the full flow worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Not related exactly to this question, but have your touchpad worked properly for last two months? I bought new XPS 15 9510 (2021) and my touchpad becomes laggy after some time of system usage (Ubuntu 21.10)

Comment: Yes it worked before and it works now again. I switched to Arch Linux where it worked too. Once again I had a problem with the touchpad but then I was able to fix it with a reboot.